# Converting .dat file to .xlsx with all data as text format in it

Tags: vbscript

I need some help on converting .dat file to .xlsx (Office 2010) and all the data in the file should be convert as text format using VBScript.

So far, I have tried the below code but I am getting data type mismatch and open text class failed error.

Code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False

objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText "C:\Users\Desktop\Hello.dat", _
xlWindows, 1, xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, ,"|" , , , , ,True,xlTextFormat, , , , ,True, Array = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

objExcel.Workbooks("Hello.dat").SaveAs _
    "C:\Users\Desktop\Hello.xlsx", 51

objExcel.Workbooks("Hello.xlsx").Close

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Hi Makyen, thank you for the reply. I tried to run the script but i am getting type mismatch (800A000D) error.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `..., Array = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`. Try removing the `Array =`. Also, are all the constants you're using (`xlWindows`, `xlDelimited`, ...) defined in your script? You must do either that or use the numeric values.

Comment: Ansgar, I have removed "Array = " from the code and added the constants Const xlWindows = 437
  Const xlDelimited = 1
  Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote = 1
  Const xlTextFormat = 2 now getting the error as Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment 'objExcel.Workbooks.Open.Text' (800A01C2)

Comment: Does the number of arguments match what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) says?

Comment: yes it is matching

Comment: Looks to me like your argument order is wrong. The first couple arguments are OK, but `"|"` should be the 12th argument, not the 6th, and `Array(...)` should be the 13th (`FieldInfo`), not the last. Please double-check.

Comment: objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText "C:\Users\Desktop\SampleScripts\Hello.dat", _
xlWindows, 1, xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, , , , , , True, "|" , Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), xlTextFormat, , ,True         Now i am getting Open Text method of Workbooks class failed error (800A03EC)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and update it with the modified code and the full error message. It's really hard to read if you dump these things in comments.